# Xcode Bundle resource missing

Tags: xcode, resources

When I build my iOS application within Xcode, it gives a build error that the video that I have added to the build folder (and added to the bundle resources) is missing: "No such file or directory". I find it strange as the following 3 or 4 times I build the application, all is fine, after which the error randomly occurs again. The only fix is then to add the files again (although they are still listed within the bundle resources).

When adding the file, I selected "copy items", "create groups" and "add to target". What could be the reason for this sudden error that randomly occurs?